# Multiplication gate in BGW in semi-honest adversary

Tags: multiparty-computation

In the [paper on high throughput MPC for 3 party computation](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2978331) it was written that for semi-honest adversary, each party is required to send three field elements to each other per multiplication gate, How? Is this about beaver triplet or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the BGW paper here: http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/136.pdf.

In order to compute a multiplication (Section 4.3.1), there is one call to Frand and one call to Fdeg-reduce. For Frand (Section 4.3.2), each party sends one field element to each other party. For Fdegreduce (Section 4.3.3), the parties run FAmat, which is Protocol 4.1 without any multiplication gates. This involves input-sharing (each party sends one field element to each other party) and output reconstruction (each party sends one field element to each other party).

Overall, each party sends 3 field elements to each other party, for a total of 6 field elements.

For 3 parties, you need at least 2 bits to describe a field with at least 3 non-zero elements. Thus, each party needs to send at least 12 bits per multiplication gate.